# Launch one instance of selenium or helium driver

Tags: python, selenium, helium

I am trying to download some images from a website (The image is changeable) and I have used the following code

```
from helium import *

for i in range(3):
    driver = start_chrome("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp", headless=True)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.screenshot(f'Number_{i}.png')
```

The code in each loop start new driver and I think this is slow somewhat. How can I be able to launch the driver for just once then to naviagte to the url several times?

I tried this

```
from helium import *

driver = start_chrome("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp", headless=True)

for i in range(3):
    driver.get("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp")
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.screenshot(f'Number_{i}.png')
```

This worked well but I am not sure if I am right of using the same url to start_chrome and then using the url again with the `get` method.

Comment: why you want to loop and take screenshot of the same element again and again ?

Comment: Just to try to take some random numbers and test them with another code to be able to extract the numbers on these captchas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from helium import *

driver =start_chrome()
for i in range(3):
    driver.get(
        "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp")
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.screenshot(f'Number_{i}.png')
```

or

```
from helium import *

driver = start_chrome(
    "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp")
for i in range(3):
    driver.refresh()
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.screenshot(f'Number_{i}.png')
```

You can use the above approach to avoid opening url twice

Comment: Can you help me of getting the numbers on such images? I tried several codes but the percent of success is about 70 % only

Comment: i didn't get you waht you mean by numbers un picture